# Play video or gif for 10 seconds, pause, click button, play for 3 seconds and jump to another timestamp in video & play for set duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, gif

I feel there's a very simple solution to this either using something like the youtube iframe api or something with jQuery / javascript or even css with animated gifs in lieu of video...? idk

I'm looking for you guys to help me confrm that it's actually possible.. any proposed solutions or starting points would be greatly appreciated.

Essentially I'd like to configure a central video div on an html page that has interactivity in the way of buttons that can provide the functionality to jump to a specific time stamp in the video then play for a specific duration and stop, but upon selecting a different button it will continue to play the video from where it paused previously for about 3-5 seconds and then jump to the section of the video identified by the button that was just clicked.

Think opening animation, Pause
user selects button, video plays to show reversal of opening animation
then video jumps to timestamp on the video that user just selected and plays for a set time
then pauses and waits for user to select different button...
.. rinse and repeat for multiple interaction points.

This needs to be mobile friendly, which I don't think will be an issue once I get a proof of concept sorted.

Thanks in advance all!

Comment: This is what i settled on using when I had a similar issue: https://plyr.io/
make sure to read the github documentation so you can become familiar with the controls and functions you will have access too, in my experience this works well on mobile also.

Comment: Thx I've taken a look at this... seems promising still working through the controls and what it can do... just wanted to thank you for suggesting it!